# Convert comma seperated string to arraylist with trailing comma sepearted

Tags: java, arraylist

How to convert the below string into java ArrayList?

I tried with line :

> "GOC,,404719160795907,911367109182460,218.248.72.40,62944,31,3331,31425,3544151354,117.200.252.120,bsnlnet,2,100.115.103.86,0,0,0,20190225123602,20190225125558,1196,,0,,,,,5428665,0,mnc071.mcc404.gprs,9448861612,Prepaid,1,,,2,255,,,,"

`List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(","))`)

but the problem is it is converting upto 255(Column) and size of the array has come to 36, but it should be 40

Comment: Do you want to keep the empty elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation of `String.split(String)`:

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the *two-argument split* method with the given expression and a limit argument of *zero*. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

You see that empty strings are not included into your array, and because your `line` ends with `,,,,` you'll lose those 4 elements, leaving you with a `List` of size 36.

To include the last elements you need to call the overload `String.split(String, int)`, like this:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(line.split(",", -1)));
```

From the documentation:

> [...] If `n` (the second parameter to `split()`) is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. [...]

Comment: instead of single comma "," better to use this regex  ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)" - this data looks like CSV.